# Duplicate files copied android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have been trying to integrate admob into my project when suddenly this error appears

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
    File1: C:\Users\SkyPunch\AndroidStudioProjects\GyanBox\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.longtailvideo.jwplayer\jwplayer-android-sdk\2.4.1+158\jars\classes.jar
    File2: C:\Users\SkyPunch\AndroidStudioProjects\GyanBox\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\9.4.0\jars\classes.jar
```

I think its an issue with same classes in two liberaries

I have used these

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.23'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.6'
    compile 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
```

How can i resolve this without removing any of the libraries

Edit: i found that by following it can be resolved

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
}
```

Will this have any impact on app. Am i excluding an important file?

Comment: I have this problem too, because  the dependencies

**
    compile 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
**

Both of the two jar have the some file :` jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml`
on the page [link](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart)

the `packagingOptions solved my problem, thanks!